# SWT Autocomplete text box

Tags: java, swt

I have a text box inside a form editor. I want it to display a subset of a 
list of strings as the user enters characters into the text box (if you 
are familiar with the google auto suggest feature, or the yahoo mail 
compose). Does anybody know where I could find these 
classes? A code snippet would be very useful. 
Thanks

Comment: Is this just SWT or can you use JFace (which makes it easy)?

Comment: yes it is only SWT... I am newbie.. how to change it to JFace?

Comment: For the core JFace code you just add the `org.eclipse.jface_xxxx` jar to your classpath.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you can include JFace in your application you can use:

```java
String [] proposals = new String [] {.... your proposals ....};

new AutoCompleteField(text, new TextContentAdapter(), proposals);
```

where `text` is your `Text` control.

You can change the proposals by calling the `setProposals` method of `AutoCompleteField`.